# Sitting at the same level as Holy Books

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, standing-sitting, holy-objects

Are you allowed to sit on **Holy** books? I am guessing you are not allowed to because you need to show respect for Holy books but is it a halacha?

What about the same level? This is a less degree of disrespect are you still able/not able to sit down

What about put them on the floor? Putting things on the floor is a slight sign of disrespect but if you place them in a nice place that does not seem disrespectful is it allowed?

In the bedroom while you sleep there? Maybe it's disrespectful to sleep in the same room as Holy Books.

Details and sources as always.

Thank You.

Comment: Are they printed or hand written can make a difference,sitting on them can never be done

Comment: "Where you sleep": Do you mean on a bed? Do you mean while you're sleeping there?

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96

Comment: "What about the same level?"  Well, what about it?

Comment: See *Ginzei Hakodesh* by Rabbi Yechezkel Feinhandler

Comment: Chiddushei Torah "_See Ginzei Hakodesh by Rabbi Yechezkel Feinhandler_" sounds like you know the answer....why not post it as such? (not snarky, serious)

Comment: @DoubleAA That's an answer. Why not post it?

Comment: @Shokhet I didn't think he was asking about a Sefer Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA See Rama there: "והוא הדין שאר ספרים"

Comment: -2 and no comments about them?

Comment: One is mine, because this question isn't clear. Explain what you mean (in the body of the question, not in a comment), and explain why it's a question in the first place.

Comment: @Shokhet I don't think he was asking about, say, a Megillat Esther.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first start with the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 282:7:

אסור לישב על המטה שספר תורה עליה.
הגה: וכל שכן שאסור להניחה על גבי קרקע. והוא הדין שאר ספרים (ב"י בשם הר"ר מנוח ובשם א"ח וכל בו). ואפילו על המדרגות שעושין לפי ארון הקדש אסור להניח ספרים (הנמי"י). ולא יניח אדם ספר תורה על ברכיו וב' אצילי ידיו עליו (מהרי"ל). ונראה לי דהוא הדין שאר ספרים

One cannot sit on the same bed as a Sefer Torah and certainly cannot place it on the floor,the same applies to other seforim,even the steps to the holy ark is assur to place seforim...(my loose translation)

The Aruch Hashulchan 282:11,12 : 
holds that turning a sefer on its face is not correct (also in Shulchan Aruch) ,sitting on a bench with seforim is also prohibited,see inside for more details.